# SQL Server FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have a table in SQL Server that looks like any other table with the column names below:

```
primaryID | column1 | column2 | column3| column4 | column5
```

I need to grab the different fields in that table and create an XML in the following format:

```
<Record>
<Field id="column1" value="ABCDEFG" />
<Field id="column2" value="Some text" />
<Field id="column3" value="Some other text" />
<Field id="column4" value="myValue" />
<Field id="column5" value="88" />
</Record>
```

In this scenario, the  node is created for each record in the table. The  node is done for every column for that particular record. 
I have tried every possible combination of RAW, PATH, ROOT, and EXPLICIT to no avail.

Is what I'm proposing even possible in SQL Server or do I need to do it somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the for xml path to get the nodes you want.

Here's a sample based on your exmample:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp  (primaryid INT, column1 VARCHAR(50), column2 VARCHAR(50), column3 VARCHAR(50) ) 
INSERT INTO #Temp (primaryid,   column1, column2, column3 ) VALUES (0, 'abc0', 'some text0', 'myvalue0')
INSERT INTO #Temp (primaryid,   column1, column2, column3 ) VALUES (1, 'abc1', 'some text1', 'myvalue1')

SELECT '',
    (
        SELECT 
            'column1' AS '@id',
            column1 AS '@value'
        FROM #temp a
        WHERE a.primaryid = #temp.primaryid
        FOR XML PATH('Field'), TYPE
    ),
    (
        SELECT 
            'column2' AS '@id',
            column2 AS '@value'
        FROM #temp a
        WHERE a.primaryid = #temp.primaryid
        FOR XML PATH('Field'), TYPE
    ),
    (
        SELECT 
            'column3' AS '@id',
            column3 AS '@value'
        FROM #temp a
        WHERE a.primaryid = #temp.primaryid
        FOR XML PATH('Field'), TYPE
    )
from #Temp
FOR XML PATH('Record'), TYPE


DROP TABLE #temp
```

The above example yields this as a result:

```
<Record>
  <Field id="column1" value="abc0" />
  <Field id="column2" value="some text0" />
  <Field id="column3" value="myvalue0" />
</Record>
<Record>
  <Field id="column1" value="abc1" />
  <Field id="column2" value="some text1" />
  <Field id="column3" value="myvalue1" />
</Record>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @Avitus answer gives you the results you need, in software development it's not only about the results, but about the readability and maintainability of the code. So I've decided to give you a couple more options:

If you don't mind to **explicitly specify column names**, here's a solutions with simple `select ... for xml`:

### 1.1. select ... for xml auto

```
select 
    (
        select *
        from (values
            ('column1', column1),
            ('column2', column2),
            ('column3', column3)
        ) as Field(id, value)
        for xml auto, type
    )
from <Table> as Record
for xml auto
```

### 1.2. select ... for xml raw

```
select
    (
        select *
        from (values
            ('column1', column1),
            ('column2', column2),
            ('column3', column3)
        ) as Field(id, value)
        for xml raw('Field'), type
    )
from <Table>
for xml raw('Record')
```

### 1.3. select ... for xml path

```
select 
    (
        select *
        from (values
            ('column1', column1),
            ('column2', column2),
            ('column3', column3)
        ) as a([@id], [@value])
        for xml path('Field'), type
    )
from <Table>
for xml path('Record')
```

More generic solutions - these allows you to **specify only columns you don't want to see** in the results:

### 2.1. Any solutions from above wrapped into dynamic SQL

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ',','') + '(''' + name + ''', ' + name + ')'
from sys.columns
where
    [object_id] = object_id('<Table>') and
    name not in ('primaryid')

select @stmt = '
        select 
            (
                select *
                from (values ' + @stmt + '
                ) as Field(id, value)
                for xml auto, type
            )
        from <Table> as Record
        for xml auto
'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```

### 2.2 Double select for xml (xml trick)

```
;with cte_xml as (
    select (select a.* for xml raw, type) as data
    from #temp as a
)
select
    (
        select  
            t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as [@id],
            t.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)') as [@value]
        from data.nodes('row/@*') as t(c)
        where t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') not in ('primaryid')
        for xml path('Field'), type
    )
from cte_xml
for xml path('Record')
```